# Electron React 404 not found in production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-react

I am building an **electron** app with **react.js**. It works fine in development mode but does not work in production mode. I have added the **main** folder inside the public and you can see my production error in the **URL** in the **main.js** code.

My folder structure

[image]

My main.js code -

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, globalShortcut, shell } = require("electron");
const isDev = require("electron-is-dev");
const path = require("path");

const getIconPath = () => {
  let ext = "png";
  if (process.platform === "darwin") {
    ext = "icns";
  }
  if (process.platform === "linux") {
    ext = "png";
  }
  if (process.platform === "win32") {
    ext = "ico";
  }
  let iconPath;
  iconPath = isDev
    ? path.join(__dirname, "..", "assets", "app_icon", `icon.${ext}`)
    : path.join(
        __dirname,
        "..",
        "..",
        "build",
        "assets",
        "app_icon",
        `icon.${ext}`
      );
  return iconPath;
};

let mainWindow;
let splash;
function createWindow() {
  splash = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600,
    height: 400,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    center: true,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    maximizable: false,
    resizable: false,
    minimizable: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
  });

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    minWidth: 500,
    minHeight: 300,
    show: false,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    icon: isDev ? getIconPath() : null,
    webPreferences: {
      contextIsolation: false,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  const mainWindowURL = isDev
    ? "http://localhost:3000"
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../", "../build/index.html")}`;

  const splashURL = isDev
    ? "http://localhost:3000/splash"
    : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "../", "../build/index.html#/splash")}`;
  splash.loadURL(splashURL);
  mainWindow.loadURL(mainWindowURL);

  splash.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    splash.show();
  });

  mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      splash.destroy();
      // maximize the window
      mainWindow.maximize();
      mainWindow.show();
    }, 3000);
  });

  // production a bad jabe
  const handleDevTools = () => {
    if (mainWindow.webContents.isDevToolsOpened()) {
      mainWindow.webContents.closeDevTools();
    } else {
      mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    }
  };
  globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+Shift+I", handleDevTools);

  // mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();

  mainWindow.on("closed", () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", function () {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
});
```

My router.js code with react-router-dom

```
import Splash from "../pages/Splash/Splash";
import Home from "../pages/Home/Home";
import Login from "../pages/Login/Login";
import Register from "../pages/Register/Register";
import { createBrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "/splash",
        element: <Splash />,
      },
      {
        path: "/login",
        element: <Login />,
      },
      {
        path: "/register",
        element: <Register />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

export default router;
```

And when I run the project in production mode built by electron-builder. This shows up the

> error -  Unexpected Application Error! 404 Not Found

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your splash window's url uses a hash (`#`), yet you use [`createBrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router). Routing on Electron and React only works with [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router), so you should replace `createBrowserRouter` with [`createHashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-hash-router).

Additionally, you might need to write the hash path outside of `path.join()`:

```
`file://${path.join(__dirname, "../", "../build/index.html")}#/splash`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already fixed it but this can be useful for others.

Comment: I was stuck with this error in my Cordova React app for some weeks. This saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After having this issue for a few days I finally discovery the [`electron-router-dom`](https://github.com/daltonmenezes/electron-app/blob/main/docs/ROUTING.md) It solves all issues using react router with Electron.

```
const { createFileRoute, createURLRoute } = require("electron-router-dom");
...
if (process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL) {
    mainWindow.loadURL(createURLRoute(process.env.ELECTRON_START_URL, "main"));
} else {
  mainWindow.loadFile(
  ...createFileRoute(path.join(__dirname, "../build/index.html"), "main")
 );
}
```

and on your App.js

```
import { Router, Route } from "electron-router-dom";
...
<Router
          main={
            <>
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={<Login />}
              />
              <Route
                path="/home"
                element={<Home />}
              />
              <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            </>
          }
        />
```