# Electron + Vite + React Unexpected Application Error! 404 Not Found in Production

Tags: reactjs, electron, vite, electron-builder

I developed a react application with vite which I am trying to convert to a desktop application using Electron. When I run electron in development mode, everything works fine; but in my production I am getting:

> Unexpected Application Error! 404 Not Found in Production

Here is **Main.js** file which is found in **electron/main** folders

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, shell, ipcMain, Menu } from 'electron'
import { release } from 'node:os'
import { join } from 'node:path'
import { update } from './update'

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
process.env.DIST_ELECTRON = join(__dirname, '../')
process.env.DIST = join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, '../dist')
process.env.PUBLIC = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL
  ? join(process.env.DIST_ELECTRON, '../public')
  : process.env.DIST

// Disable GPU Acceleration for Windows 7
if (release().startsWith('6.1')) app.disableHardwareAcceleration()

// Set application name for Windows 10+ notifications
if (process.platform === 'win32') app.setAppUserModelId(app.getName())

if (!app.requestSingleInstanceLock()) {
  app.quit()
  process.exit(0)
}

// Remove electron security warnings
// This warning only shows in development mode
// Read more on https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security
// process.env['ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS'] = 'true'

let win: BrowserWindow | null = null
// Here, you can also use other preload
const preload = join(__dirname, '../preload/index.js')
const url = process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL;
const indexHtml = join(process.env.DIST, 'index.html')
//const indexHtml = join(__dirname, '../../index.html')

async function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'Dispute Resolution',
    icon: join(process.env.PUBLIC, 'light.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      preload,
      // Warning: Enable nodeIntegration and disable contextIsolation is not secure in production
      // Consider using contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld
      // Read more on https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      //devTools: false // This will disable dev tools
    },
  })

  Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

  if(isDev){
   // win.webContents.openDevTools;
    //win.webContents.closeDevTools
  }

 if (url) { // electron-vite-vue#298
    win.loadURL(url)
    // Open devTool if the app is not packaged
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
    
  } else {
    win.loadFile(indexHtml);
    win.webContents.openDevTools()
  }

  // Test actively push message to the Electron-Renderer
  /*win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
    win?.webContents.send('main-process-message', new Date().toLocaleString())
  })*/

  // Make all links open with the browser, not with the application
  win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({ url }) => {
    if (url.startsWith('https:')) shell.openExternal(url)
    return { action: 'deny' }
  })

  // Apply electron-updater
  update(win)
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  win = null
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('second-instance', () => {
  if (win) {
    // Focus on the main window if the user tried to open another
    if (win.isMinimized()) win.restore()
    win.focus()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  const allWindows = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()
  if (allWindows.length) {
    allWindows[0].focus()
  } else {
    createWindow()
  }
})

// New window example arg: new windows url
ipcMain.handle('open-win', (_, arg) => {
  const childWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      preload,
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
    },
  })

  if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    childWindow.loadURL(`${url}#${arg}`)
  } else {
    childWindow.loadFile(indexHtml, { hash: arg })
  }
})
```

**App.jsx**

```
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Register from './components/Register/Register';
import Otp from './components/Otp/otp';
// Private Routes
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard Section/Dashboard';
import ForgotPassword from './components/ForgotPassword/ForgotPassword';
import PasswordUpdate from './components/PasswordUpdate/PasswordUpdate';
import Profile from './components/Profile/Profile';
import RaiseDispute from './components/Raise Dispute/RaiseDispute'
import DisputeListing from './components/Dispute Listing/DisputeListing'
import Transactions from './components/Transactions Listing/Transactions';




import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider
} from 'react-router-dom';

//Create router

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <div><Login /></div>
},
{
  path: '/Register',
  element: <div><Register /></div>
},
{
  path: '/Otp',
  element: <div><Otp /></div>
},
{

  path: '/Dashboard',
  element: <div className='container'><Dashboard/></div>
},
{

  path: '/raise-dispute',
  element: <div className='container'><RaiseDispute/></div>
},
{

  path: '/disputes-listing',
  element: <div className='container'><DisputeListing/></div>
},
{

  path: '/transactions-listing',
  element: <div className='container'><Transactions/></div>
}
])


function App() {
  

  return (
   
      <div>
        <RouterProvider router = {router} />
        
      </div>
    
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron React 404 not found in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75637194/electron-react-404-not-found-in-production)

Comment: @Arkellys Thanks for your response. It displayed the first page but when I  click on other url I got *Not Found (error 404)*. And also images are not displaying.

Comment: The images are not displayed because you most likely forgot to set [`base: ""`](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) in your Vite config.

Comment: And if the other links are not working then you probably have another bad configuration with hash somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There might be 2 solutions for this case:

1. Using basename. 
   `const router = createBrowserRouter(routes, { basename: import.meta.env.BASE_URL }`

**NOTE:** If you specified a different base in `vite.config.js` then I recommend you to care about this situation for all the routes.

2. Using Memory Router instead of Browser Router.

```
    import { createMemoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const router = createMemoryRouter([
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <div><Login /></div>
    },
    {
      path: '/Register',
      element: <div><Register /></div>
    },
    {
      path: '/Otp',
      element: <div><Otp /></div>
    },
    {
    
      path: '/Dashboard',
      element: <div className='container'><Dashboard/></div>
    },
    {
    
      path: '/raise-dispute',
      element: <div className='container'><RaiseDispute/></div>
    },
    {
    
      path: '/disputes-listing',
      element: <div className='container'><DisputeListing/></div>
    },
    {
    
      path: '/transactions-listing',
      element: <div className='container'><Transactions/></div>
    }
    ])
```

3. **[UPDATE: 7 Jan 2024]** Recently, I've found [HashRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/hash-router), because MemoryRouter does not reflect the changes to the `window.location` and for this reason I can't see or send any data over URL.

I needed to get URL params for some scenarios and I migrated to Hash Router. If you need to manipulate location, or need to get some data from url like `localhost:5173/#/blog/:id` or `localhost:5173/#/join?token={token}`, then you should pick HashRouter instead of MemoryRouter.

```
    import { createHashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    
    const router = createHashRouter([
      {
        path: '/',
        element: <div><Login /></div>
      },
      ...
    ]
```

And, for the record, if you go with `HashRouter`, then all of your routes are going to be like this: `localhost:5173/#/login`

There always be a `#` symbol.